# What is expected to be hidden under the value of fortifyBasicAuthId parameter of fortifyScan pipeline stage?

Tags: s4sdk

I'm adapting s/4 sdk pipeline for our project and would like to introduce fortify scan stage within the pipeline.

[Here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#fortifyscan) I could find parameters that the **fortifyScan** stage requires:

```
fortifyScan:
    sscUrl: 'https://fortify.dummy.corp.domain/ssc'
    fortifyApiCredentialId: 'FortifyApiToken'
    fortifyBasicAuthId: 'FortifyBasicAuth'
    fortifyProjectName: 'mySampleProject'
    projectVersionId: '12345'
```

From the [source code of s/4 sdk pipeline lib](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib/blob/master/vars/stageFortifyScan.groovy#L70) I can derive that secret hidden under the value of **fortifyBasicAuthId** is placed into the **Authorization** header with prefix "Basic ".

What is expected there as the secret? Is it really Base64 encoded bytes of **"user:password"** pair belonging to user that has access to my Fortify project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right the value is the base64 encoded string of `user:password`. The user has to be a Fortify user with permissions to the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.